# What does @Group and @GroupThreads refer to in jmh?

Tags: java, jmh

I have been looking at the way jmh implements the "multithreaded" benchmarks. From my understanding, the annotations `@Group("Identifier")` and `@GroupThreads(thread_number)` enable running in parallel the benchmarks that are within the same Group.

```
@Benchmark
@Group("parallel")
@GroupThreads(1)
public void benchmark_1() {
    while(true) {}
}

@Benchmark
@Group("parallel")
@GroupThreads(1)
public void benchmark_2() {
    while(true) {}
}
```

Using the CPU monitor, I get that two CPU's are fully used.
I would like to know how does the runner interpret those annotations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried reading Javadocs? Are those not answering the question?

E.g. `@Group` says:

```
 * <p>Multiple {@link Benchmark} methods can be bound in the execution group
 * to produce the asymmetric benchmark. Each execution group contains of one
 * or more threads. Each thread within a particular execution group executes
 * one of {@link Group}-annotated {@link Benchmark} methods. The number of
 * threads executing a particular {@link Benchmark} defaults to a single thread,
 * and can be overridden by {@link GroupThreads}.</p>
 *
 * <p>Multiple copies of an execution group may participate in the run, and
 * the number of groups depends on the number of worker threads requested.
 * JMH will take the requested number of worker threads, round it up to execution
 * group size, and then distribute the threads among the (multiple) groups.
 * Among other things, this guarantees fully-populated execution groups.</p>

 * <p>For example, running {@link Group} with two {@link Benchmark} methods,
 * each having {@link GroupThreads}(4), will run 8*N threads, where N is an
 * integer.</p>
```

So, `@Group` produces an asymmetric benchmark, `@GroupThreads` controls the distribution of threads within the group (`-tg ...` in CLI dubs it). `@Threads` say how many threads to run in total (`-t ...` in CLI dubs it).

Comment: I still don't understand that now how does the threads of the execution group behaves, for example in sample 15 of jmh, three threads will call counter.incrementAndGet() and one thread will call counter.get(). Does the four threads behaves sequentially (meaning that the last thread will wait until the three threads are done updating and then get the value) or in parallel.

Comment: Asymmetric benchmarks behave the same way as symmetric ones, modulo the differences outlined in `@Group` Javadoc. Now, symmetric benchmarks run all threads in parallel. Does it say anywhere in Javadocs asymmetric benchmarks *do not* run threads in parallel?

Comment: so If the threads are running in parallel that means that there is some synchronization strategy done by the runner to control threads behavior, or is it OS arbitration ?

Comment: Wait, what? Of course there is *some* level of synchronization involved to access benchmark states, controlling the threads, etc. -- but that is required for the regular symmetric benchmarks as well. Of course, there is *some* OS arbitration involved when scheduling the threads on the real processors, especially when more threads than CPUs are requested..

Comment: Okay,I would like to take a look at the synchronization mechanism used. Could you please refer me to the corresponding class in jmh sources.

Comment: `BenchmarkHandler` and `BenchmarkHandler.BenchmarkTask`, that will call into the generated stub somewhere in your `.../target/generated-sources/`. But it still baffles me what you are expecting to find there. Asymmetric benchmarks differ in the way they choose what `@Benchmark` method to call, nothing really else.

Comment: I just want to know the mechanics of that to undersand the jmh API better.

Comment: All right, dig in. But a fair word of warning: relying on implementation details is dangerous. You can peek into the implementation, but don't make the mistake of assuming the implementation would stay the same.